# How do I use a zsh function's return in a boolean?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to create a function which checks if a directory exists and returns `1` if it does or `0` otherwise. It's an utility function which I then use inside an `if` statement. Here is the code:

```
function bean-exists {
  if (( $# < 1 )); then
    print "usage: $0 BEAN_NAME" >&2
    exit -1
  fi

  if [[ -e "${YAHMDIR}/beans/$1" ]]; then
    echo "FOUND"
    return 1
  fi

  return -1
}    

if (bean-exists "hosts"); then
  echo YEAH
else
  echo NOPS
fi
```

I don't know why, but this is printing

```
FOUND
NOPS
```

When, if FOUND it should print YEAH. Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unix shells (contrary to many other programming languages) `0` stands for *true* and any other (integer) value stands for *false*. This goes in hand with Unix programs returning `0` on successful completion and any other value (usually between 1 and 255) indicates some negative result or error.

So you should return `0` if the file exists and `1` if it does not.

As you are returning `1` the `if` interpretes this as `false` and goes to the `else` branch.

Your function acutally *does* `return 1` at the end, if the file is not found. This is correct, but from your description I would have expected `return 0`.

Comment: Thank you! That `return 1` in the end was a typo. The original code had a `return -1`. I fixed it so it doesn't confuse someone looking at the question.